# How do I use a QueryDSL BooleanExpression in a Hibernate Search query?

Tags: querydsl, hibernate-search

I have a complex, reusable method that returns a BooleanExpression to filter a Q object `QPost`.

How do I use this BooleanExpression in a Hibernate Search query like this:

```java
Search.session(entityManager).search(Post.class)
                .where(f -> {
                    var boolStep = f.bool()
                            .must(f.match().fields("title", "text", "author.name").matching(searchText))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean an expression built using [the QueryDSL project](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl)?

That project [still uses Hibernate Search 5](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/cd608f04ed7534b1b62a78a28beb141071d149b6/querydsl-hibernate-search/pom.xml#L28), not 6, so currently you cannot use it with Hibernate Search 6.

Perhaps you should create an issue on that project, and if you can, contribute the upgrade yourself?